# Keep door closed until handle is turned

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking for a door model that will not open until the handle is turned.

At present I have tried the hinged_door and heavy_door models from the database and they can just be pushed open regardless of the state of the handle.

Can someone please direct me to a model/ world file that achieves this? Or can it be done with the existing models and am I doing something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15001/keep-door-closed-until-handle-is-turned/) by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-12-12**:
You could modify the existing models with a model plugin which implements the behaviour you want. I imagine someone might have done this before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Chapulina has suggested a model plugin, which is definitely a good choice. Or, just make the latch mechanically! Unless you'd rather write code to do it, I a simple mechanical latch would be easy. Take advantage of the fact that you have real physics

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [snakeplisk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2466/snakeplisk/) on 2016-12-14**:
Thanks Peter, I will try both of those options.